# How do I find a dynamically added TableLayoutPanel control in tab control of a winform

Tags: findcontrol, tablelayoutpanel

Need help finding a TableLayoutPanel added at run time to a tab control of a winform.  Please find example code below.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
private void GenerateControls()
{
   TableLayoutPanel tp = new TableLayoutPanel();
   tp.Name = "tpName";
   tab1.Controls.Add(tp);
}

private void findTablePanelControl()
{
    TableLayoutPanel tp = (TableLayoutPanel)this.Controls.Find("tpName", true)[0];
    string name = tp.Name;
}
```

I receive the follow error message: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

I also tried the following code, but get this error (Object reference not set to an instance of an object) on the "string name =" line:

```
TableLayoutPanel tpParseSchema = (TableLayoutPanel)this.Controls.Find("tpParseSchema", true).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I found the problem.  The provide example code actual work.  The problem with my real code was that I mistakenly keyed in the wrong name value for the panel.  I ended up figuring this out by recursively stepping through all of the child controls of the tab control.  Here is example code of how I did that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  The provided example code actually will work.  The problem with my real code was that I mistakenly keyed in the wrong name value for the TableLayoutPanel.  I ended up figuring this out by recursively stepping through all of the child controls of the tab control.  Here is example code of how I did that.

```
foreach (Control ctrl in tab1.Controls)
{
   string ctrlname = ctrl.Name;
}
```